# Laptop power options while flying

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I have noticed some laptop power supplies include a plug that allows you to connect it to a power source while flying.  If I was going to go out and buy a laptop power supply for this purpose, which one should I consider?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [**The Ultimate Guide to In-Seat Laptop Power Ports**](http://www.seatguru.com/articles/in-seat_laptop_power.php)
- Another interesting read at Google Answers [**Laptop power on an airplane**](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/475832.html)
- Some [brand wise references at this commercial site](http://www.priorityelectronics.com/laptop-airplane-adapter.htm).